# How to position an image in between 2 sections?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position an image in between two sections with a ratio of 30:70 (top/bottom).

I have tried nesting the image within a parent and giving that 'position: relative' and then giving the image itself 'position: absolute' to no avail..

Thanks!

```css
.imageParent {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="imageParent">
            <img class ='image' src='./assets/image-2.jpeg' alt='picture of a man sitting down viewing graphs off an iPad'>
    </div>
```

What I [got](https://gyazo.com/e49ac552e6b9bc8a6876e8908cb10465)

What I [need](https://gyazo.com/bdfd4f03f15dbbba1d3bed5f201bf670)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.imageParent {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-30%);
}

.topdiv{
 background: #ed145b;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 110px 0 150px 0;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis labore, voluptates nostrum nulla repudiandae. Dolorem quo, inventore numquam aliquam pariatur.</p>
</div>
<div class="imageParent">
    <img class ='image' src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/300' alt='picture of a man sitting down viewing graphs off an iPad'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to set up each section with the desired ratio, and wrap both sections in a container that has "relative" positioning. The image element would then be placed with "absolute" positioning where the top position is 70% to line up with the boundary of the two sections.

Finally, the image can then be centered relative to it's top left corner by adding:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

In code this would look like:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height:100vh; 
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  
  /* Center the top-left position of the img */
  top: 30%;
  left:50%;
  
    /* Center relative to the diving line */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pink {
  background:pink;
  height:30%;
}

.grey {
  background:grey;
  height:70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="pink">Section 1</section>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x50" />
  <section class="grey">Section 2</section>
</div>
```